# Request derivative and integral problems bank

Tags: integration, reference-request

I need derivative and integral problems in many numbers (I prefer >100 questions, multiple sources are okay).

**Scope: Start from high school material then raise to pre-college. Derivative, trigonometry derivative, indefinite integral, definite integral. Partial integral is okay, but not too much. Logarithmic, natural, etc. are okay also.**

I also prefer difficult question like these:

[Trigonometric function integration: $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2 \sin^2x)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402223/trigonometric-function-integration-int-0-pi-2-fracdxa2-cos2xb2-si)

[A definite integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{2-\cos x}{\left(1+x^4\right)\,\left(5-4\cos x\right)}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508308/a-definite-integral-int-0-infty-frac2-cos-x-left1x4-right-left5-4)

[Integral $\int_{-1}^1\frac1x\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln\left(\frac{2\,x^2+2\,x+1}{2\,x^2-2\,x+1}\right) \ \mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1?rq=1)

[Integral ${\large\int}_0^1\left(-\frac{\operatorname{li} x}x\right)^adx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951621/integral-large-int-01-left-frac-operatornameli-xx-rightadx)

Even this one is okay too:

[Prove ${\large\int}_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{9+4\sqrt5\,x}\ \left(1-x^2\right)^{2/3}}=\frac{3^{3/2}}{2^{4/3}5^{5/6}\pi }\Gamma^3\left(\frac13\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879854/prove-large-int-11-fracdx-sqrt394-sqrt5-x-left1-x2-right?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com board.
There are lots of interesting and nontrivial integrals, solved in details, often with several different approaches.

Take a look at forums [Contests](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/forum12.html), [Computation of Integrals](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/forum3.html).

I can also recommend reading Victor Moll's papers on integrals (e.g. [these ones](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Victor+Moll+The+integrals+in+Gradshteyn+and+Ryzhik)).

Comment: As far, this answer is suitable for my need! Thank you!